# Почему тормозит INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: mysql

Собственно говоря есть у меня огромная база, на несколько террабайт. Хочу вытащить FK для нее, где-то таким запросом

```
SELECT 
    kcu.`TABLE_NAME` AS dstTable,
    kcu.`COLUMN_NAME` AS dstColumn
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu
WHERE kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = :schemaName 
    AND kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = :tableName;
    AND kcu.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = :columnName
```

Казалось бы ничего страшного. Но ответа приходится ждать по минуте. Может я что-то не так делаю? Как список FK вытягивают SQL клиенты?
Может нужно в настройках что-то приписать?

**MySQL 5.5.54-0+deb8u1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось намного проще

```
SET @PREV_STATE = @@GLOBAL.innodb_stats_on_metadata;
SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata=0;

SELECT 
    kcu.`TABLE_NAME` AS dstTable,
    kcu.`COLUMN_NAME` AS dstColumn
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu
WHERE kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = :schemaName 
    AND kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = :tableName
    AND kcu.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = :columnName;

SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata=@PREV_STATE;
```